# MySQL trigger before insert with INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is MySQL trigger which is set before insert to certain table, executed when I call INSERT IGNORE and inserting is ignored?

Comment: Have a look at this [discussion](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13473).  In other databases, such as Oracle, the trigger fires even if no insert ends up happening.  This appears to be the same behavior in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a demonstration:

```
mysql> create table foo (foo_id int primary key);

mysql> create table bar (foo_id int);

mysql> create trigger foo_ins before insert on foo 
       for each row insert into bar set foo_id = new.foo_id;

mysql> insert ignore into foo set foo_id=123;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into foo set foo_id=123;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

This should have inserted just one row in the foo table, because the second try would conflict with the primary key value. We see that the second insert affects 0 rows, which means no new row was inserted.

Let's see what the effect on the bar table is:

```
mysql> select * from bar;
+--------+
| foo_id |
+--------+
|    123 |
|    123 |
+--------+
```

Two rows were inserted. This proves that the trigger is fired even when doing insert ignore.

Comment: Yes, i tried it too, but you were faster with answer.
Is there some option to stop executing trigger when row is ignored?

Comment: @Jan, The only solution I can think of is to put your code in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. If an error occurs that makes the insert not happen (like violating a unique constraint or a not null constraint), it will abort before it gets to execute the AFTER trigger.

Comment: yes i would like to use `AFTER INSERT` trigger, but there is already another one which is more important and I dont want to mix another logic in it.

Comment: @Jan, are you use MySQL 5.7? You can have multiple triggers with the same time and event. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html under "trigger_order".

Comment: We are using MySQL 5.6.34, but we are considering to change it with MariaDB. But at the moment it is not possible.
Thanks for this information.